# How to download an image with document mime-type?

Tags: javascript, php, image, download, mime-types

Please take a look at this url :
https://lh6.ggpht.com/uxLXvxuncWOm2mgU3ChtdGZ0eMp_WJTD4xrVxAKqCJMiR5ibaBbw-VUPJPjcGiqIDRbm=h310
This link refers to an screenshot of Facebook app on google play.

 As you can see, The mime-type for this link is document.
What's this image's real extension ? 
Actually, I have a list of +10k screenshots and I want to download them to my local hard disk with exactly the same name as the image url. But I don't know how . (I could do it easily if there was a known image mime-type on these links, But now that mime-type is document, And files don't have an extension , I don't know how )

Comment: The mime-time for that link is `image/png` in my browser..

Comment: Here is document, In my browser (chrome).
How can I download those images with the same name as url ?

Comment: You can see here that the `content-type` is `image/png`: http://i.imgur.com/LLxpdsK.png. If you have a set of URLs, can't you just do GET requests for all of them and save the resources?

Comment: where does `document` come from?...content-type header is clearly `image/png`. Really not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

The mime-type returned by the server is not `document`, it is actually `image/png`.

You can get the mime-type returned by the server with code like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://lh6.ggpht.com/uxLXvxuncWOm2mgU3ChtdGZ0eMp_WJTD4xrVxAKqCJMiR5ibaBbw-VUPJPjcGiqIDRbm=h310");
request.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var type = this.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
    console.log(type);
});
request.send();
```